# Connecting to offline server with no password but still getting Packet Type of 1 [MINECRAFT]

Tags: node.js, typescript, minecraft, packet

Currently I am attempting to make a Node.JS implementation for logging into (and interacting with) servers for a future project, and for some reason (even though I have specified that I am connecting to localhost with no password) everytime I send the request, I get a response from the socket with Packet Type [0x01](https://wiki.vg/Protocol#Encryption_Request) - despite the documentation (https://wiki.vg) stating:

> For unauthenticated ("cracked"/offline-mode) and localhost connections (either of the two conditions is enough for an unencrypted connection) there is no encryption. In that case Login Start is directly followed by Login Success.

My code currently looks like this (incompleted due to this issue arising):

```
    async function Offline(Settings : IClientSettingsParsed) {
    const start = Date.now();

    let User = Settings.user;
    let Server = Settings.server;

    const socket = await TCPSocket.connect(Server.host, Server.port);
    try {
        {
            const handshake = new Packet();
            handshake.writeVarInt(0x00);
            handshake.writeVarInt(Settings.version);
            handshake.writeString(Server.host, true);
            handshake.writeUShortBE(Server.port);
            handshake.writeVarInt(2);
            await socket.writePacket(handshake, true);

            const start = new Packet();
            start.writeVarInt(0x00);
            start.writeString(User.username, true);
            await socket.writePacket(start, true);
        }
        const response = await Packet.from(socket);
        const type = response.readVarInt();

        return type;
    } finally {
        await socket.dispose();
    }
}

it("Should create a new player in offline mode", () => {
    let Settings : IClientSettings = {
      username: "Bot",
      server: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 61001,
        offline: true
      },
      version: EVersion["1.8.9"]
    }
    return Login(Settings).then((result) => {
      expect(result).toBe('a');
    });
  });
```

Note: they are in different files